# Using Vue package in Administration component Shopware 6

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component, shopware, shopware6

I want to use an Vue package like this
Vue.use(npmPackageName)
but when I import vue form 'vue' this message appear "Can’t resolve vue"
my question is how can I use npm package in the administration component?
thanks a lot.

this is the npm_modules folder

[image]

and this is the webpack.config.js file
[image]

here is how i try to import and use it
[image]

Comment: Try to post code as code-blocks, not as screenshots, so other's might be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post the full output of your build command, maybe on pastebin.com ?

Comment: yes this is the output https://pastebin.com/crdXatjY

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

You have to add the package to your own module's `package.json` and the `build-administration.sh` would install the dependencies.

This works only, [if `jq` is installed on your system](https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/aaf0402700d23e542aba1c40092513a932f8b8d4/bin/build-administration.sh#L32) - otherwise a warning is printed which can be overseen easily.

Comment: i already add the package to the package.json file but when I import the vue as < import Vue from 'vue' > to call "use" function as " Vue.use(packageName)" this error appears "ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' "

Comment: Is the vue package in your `node_modules` folder?

Comment: yes the package inside the node_modules folder

Comment: I have been editing my question with some images can you check it, please @Alex

Comment: So actually the problem seems to be to resolve `vue` which is a part of Shopware already, not the package..